# Excel VBA - Macro to transpose a range, then turn it into a pivot table

Tags: vba, transpose

I'm attempting to take a range of data, transpose it and then turn it into a pivot table.

I've written the code to grab the data, copy/paste/transpose it.  I would then assume I turn that selection into a Pivot cache.

I'm wondering though, if there's a more efficient way to take the original selection, transpose it directly into a pivot cache in order to create the pivot table.  In a sense, skipping over the paste.

In other words, can I define the Pivot Cache as the range, transposed, without actually copying and pasting it? I'm really just trying to get a sense of whether this is possible or not, or if I should just proceed with the copy, pastespecial transpose = true, and then turn that result into a pivot table.  This option, however, seems a bit long winded, so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient direction to go in.

```
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
ActiveSheet.Cells(12, 1).Select
Selection.Resize(38, n + 3).Copy


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "PIVOT"
Worksheets("Pivot").Range("A1").PasteSpecial transpose:=True
```

My new approach is to declare the original data as a range, then declare that range as a transposed range, and then attempt to declare that transposed range as the pivot cache.

```
Dim Trange As Range
Set Trange = Range(Sheets("Control Panel").Cells(12, 1), Sheets("control panel").Cells(38, n + 3))

Range(Sheets("Pivot").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Pivot").Cells(n + 3, 38)).Value = Application.transpose(Trange)
```

With this last line of code, I've gotten the data to appear on the Pivot worksheet, transposed.

Ultimately, however, I'm trying to put this data in transposed form, straight into a pivot cache, without having to have it appear on the worksheet.

Comment: I'm thinking of maybe declaring the original data range as a range, and then transposing that range in VBA without pasting it, and then declaring the transposed range as the pivot cache.

Comment: maybe create pivot cache from a recordset https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/create-a-pivottable-from-a-vba-array-help.3908627/